# Making someone tired vs. Tiring someone out

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-choice, sentence-usage

What is the exact difference between

1. **Making someone tired**
2. **Getting someone tired**
3. **Having someone tired**
4. **Tiring someone out**

1,2, and 3 are used when you are doing something to or on someone against their will 
but I am confused about 4th one, tiring someone out is also something that is against the will of someone I mean no body wants to feel tired willingly. 
So what is the exact difference between these sentences?

Comment: Neither 2 or 3 sound correct in US English.

Comment: @stangdon Then what about 1st and 4th? I mean do they have similar meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at each sentence.

1. **Making someone tired**

You would use this like "This work is *making me tired*" or "Listening to Phillip was *making him tired*".  It isn't exactly about doing something to someone against their will; it is just about something having an effect on someone: the subject is causing the object to be tired.

2. **Getting someone tired**

This is not idiomatic or fluent.  We do use *get* with *tired*, but we would use it like this: "I am *getting tired*" or "Jonathan was *getting tired* of listening to Phillip".  *Getting* in this sense just means *becoming*.  We don't usually use it transitively, like "This work is getting me tired."  The use of "**get** *adjective*" seems to be very tricky for English learners, so I recommend that they avoid it until they have studied it thoroughly.

3. **Having someone tired**

This is also not idiomatic or fluent.  Don't use it.

4. **Tiring someone out**

We would use this like #1.  "This hard work is *tiring me out*" or "Listening to Phillip was *tiring Jonathan out*."  It's more informal than #1, and also implies "very tired" or "completely tired".

Comment: @J.R. O.k I will keep that in mind.